Find closed form expression for inverse matrix
I have the following matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 2^p - 2 & 3^p - 2 \cdot 2^p + 1 & 4^p - 2 \cdot 3^p + 2^p \dots  & n^p - 2 \cdot (n - 1)^p + (n - 2)^p \\
    2^p - 2 & 2 & 2^p - 2 & 3^p - 2 \cdot 2^p + 1 \dots  & (n - 1)^p - 2 \cdot (n - 2)^p + (n - 2)^p \\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
    n^p - 2 \cdot (n - 1)^p + (n - 2)^p & \dots & \dots & \dots  & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where $a_{ij} = |j - i + 1|^p - 2 \cdot |j - i|^p + |j - i - 1|^p$, $p \in (0, 2)$.
I try to find closed form for elements of its inverse matrix.
I see that it is symmetric Toeplitz matrix, but I don't know, how to use it here. I also tried to represent it as product of two matrices in order to get rid of differences in $a_{ij}$ formulas, but they are not quadratic. I will be very thankful for everybody's help!
